# CSS getting completely removed by Chrome Browser

Tags: html, css

Only half of these are actually being applied!

```
.btn{
    background-color: darkorange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10x 25px;
    border-radius: 30px;
```

Any Ideas

Comment: Use your browser devtool inspect facility to see exactly what CSS is being applied where.

Comment: Where, what, and when? The how can be answered with more details. Welcome to SO btw.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it’s being overruled by CSS specificity.

You can try to override the specificity using

```
!important
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an anchor tag with .btn class. and use your css I made only one important changes. after this changes all css property is working.

Displays an element as an inline element (like `<a>`). Any height and width properties will have no effect.
so I did set `display:inline-block;` because The element itself is formatted as an inline element, but you can apply height and width values

```
.btn{
    background-color: darkorange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

if it is helpful for you let me know.